# Progress bar with duration and percentage

Tags: javascript, jquery, progress-bar

I want to create a progress bar that has a duration ( the time that it takes to finish the animation) and a percentage.

So I want this progress bar to take 3000ms to finish ( to get to 100%):

So far :

```
  <div id="box"></div>

  <script>
     function start(){
          var duration = 5000; // it should finish in 5 seconds !
         var max = 100;
         var i = 0 ;
         var interval = setInterval(function(){
            i++;
            offset  = (max*i)/duration;
            console.log(offset);
            $("#box").css("width", offset + "px");
            $("#box").text(parseInt(offset) + "%");
            if(i>=duration){
                alert("done "+i);
                clearInterval(interval);
            }
        }, 1);


      }
  </script>
```

It works but it takes way longer that 5000ms .

I've also added Jquery tag because I don't care if I do this with javascript or jquery

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest solution could be is ot use jQuery's [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

```js
function start() {
  var duration = 5000; // it should finish in 5 seconds !
  $("#box").stop().css("width", 0).animate({
    width: 100
  }, {
    duration: duration,
    progress: function(promise, progress, ms) {
      $(this).text(Math.round(progress * 100) + '%');
    }
  });
}

start()
```

```css
#box {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box"></div>
```

another solution will be is to look at the time difference

```js
function start() {
  var duration = 5000; // it should finish in 5 seconds !
  var st = new Date().getTime();
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    var diff = Math.round(new Date().getTime() - st),
      val = Math.round(diff / duration * 100);
    val = val > 100 ? 100 : val;
    $("#box").css("width", val + "px");
    $("#box").text(val + "%");
    if (diff >= duration) {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, 100);
}

start()
```

```css
#box {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box"></div>
```

---

Same using [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame#Browser_compatibility)

```js
function start() {
  var duration = 5000; // it should finish in 5 seconds !
  var st = window.performance.now();
  window.requestAnimationFrame(function step(time) {
    var diff = Math.round(time - st),
      val = Math.round(diff / duration * 100);
    val = val > 100 ? 100 : val;
    $("#box").css("width", val + "px");
    $("#box").text(val + "%");
    if (diff < duration) {
      window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
    }
  })
}

start()
```

```css
#box {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box"></div>
```

Comment: I thing that the best approach must see the progress of AJAX call from method post using enctype="multipart/form-data". Progress bar based on time duration don't catch the real use of progress bar

Answer (score 8):

Feel free to tweak the below as needed, but the main problems are fixed.  Namely, your interval shouldn't be running every 1 millisecond, and it should complete at 100%.  The below will set your interval to always run at each 1%.

```
function start(){
     var duration = 5000; // it should finish in 5 seconds !
     var percent = duration / 100; // 1 percent of duration
     var i = 0 ;
     var interval = setInterval(function(){
        i++;
        $("#box").css("width", i + "px");
        $("#box").text(i + "%");
        if(i>=100){
            alert("done");
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, percent);


}
```

Comment: The reason the original was not finishing on time is that the minimum duration for setInterval is 4ms. If you go under that, the browser will use 4ms instead. The code that executes inside the interval might take longer than 4ms, which would slow it down further still. This code is better, because you only need to update the text/progress bar once every 1 percent, or only 100 times vs 5000.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're using it yet, but you could bootstrap to do this.

```
<div class="progress-bar" style="width: 0;" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" >


var value = 0;

function start(){
    value += 5;
    $( ".progress-bar" ).css("width", value+"%").attr("aria-valuenow", value);    
    if ( value%5 == 0 ) { 
        return setTimeout(restart, 100); 
    }
    if(value >= 100)
        return;
    else
        setTimeout(restart, 50);
}

function restart() {
    start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the answer provided by some of you but you got one thing wrong on the progress bar. You need to change the "px" in jquery to be "%" otherwise the progress bar will only be 100px wide. Since I am using the Bootstrap Progress bar the values here amend to what is already there and fill up the progress wrapper as the page loads.

```
 function start() {
 var duration = 5000; // it should finish in 5 seconds !
 var st = window.performance.now();
 window.requestAnimationFrame(function step(time) {
 var diff = Math.round(time - st),
 val = Math.round(diff / duration * 100);
 val = val > 100 ? 100 : val;
 $(".progress-bar").css("width", val + "%");
 $(".progress-bar").text(val + "%");
 if (diff < duration) {
   window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
   }
 })
}
start()
```